# Read custom RSS tag

Tags: c#, rss

I am relatively new to programming and I am trying to write a programm that gets the items from a rss document and puts out the content I want into a Datagrid and into Teamspeak. So far I am able to get the Title of the items and remove the Minutes from the Title since there is an custom RSS tag that says: `wf:expiry`.

My problem is that I am unable to access that element right now.
My approach is to get the expiry, get the current DateTime, create a timespan of both to timevalid = expiry - current and then just count down timevalid-- to then hand it over to my UpdateData function `UpdateData(subject, timevalid--);`

```
public void GetData()
{
    // set the RSS URL and init the XML Reader
    string url = "http://content.warframe.com/dynamic/rss.php";
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    reader.Close();

    foreach (string s in feed.ElementExtensions.ReadElementExtensions<string>("wf:expiry", ""))
    {
        ConnectionLabel.Content = s;
    }

    // go thru each item
    foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
    {
        String subject = item.Title.Text;
        // Adding the Item if the ID isnt already added
        if (!listRSS.ContainsKey(item.Id))
        {
            // remove the Minute Label from the Title to prepare parsing the expiry date and use this as the basis of the timer
            if (subject.EndsWith("m"))
            {
                // this will remove all characters in the string.
                // pattern would be "data - XXm" so remove the " - XXm" part
                char[] blacklist = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'm', '-', ' ' };
                subject = subject.TrimEnd(blacklist);
            }
            // add the ID to listRSS to be able to compare the GUID of the Alert to the ones in the List to avoid adding Alerts that had been already added
            listRSS.Add(item.Id, subject);
            // hand over the subject to update the Datagrid
            UpdateData(subject);
        }
    }
}
```

So my Question is, can I hand over a Datagrid Insert with a timevalid-- so it counts down the time in the wpf app?

and I would love to learn how I can access the `wf:expiry` element and parse its insides to convert it to `DateTime`. i would love a solution if anyone is up to it so I could read the code and see the approach.

I just learned this all by contributing to github but I mainly did xaml code since i am more interested in UI. This is my first Project ever.

Comment: Could you please try feed.ElementExtensions.ReadElementExtensions<string>("expiry", "wf")

Comment: `foreach (string s in feed.ElementExtensions.ReadElementExtensions<string>("expiry", "wf"))
            {
                Tester.Items.Add(s);
            }` seem to add nothing